# Turn JQuery Star Rating into Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/no1_melman/aCY3x/), it's pretty cool, my first attempt at creating a jquery control. It is simple, just a star ratings control.

I want to be able to turn this into a control, so that, I can call:

```
$('#someDiv').starRating();
```

And it turns that div into a star rating.

I would like to be able to then setup some properties:

1. Empty Star Source
2. Hover Star Source
3. Star Rating (leave blank if new rating)

So it would look something like this:

```
$('#someDiv').starRating({
    emptyStarSource : 'http://www.imageland.com/image.png',
    hoverStarSource : 'http://www.imageland.com/image.png',
    initialRating : 3
});
```

Similar to the Datepicker in how to change options etc.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

***EDIT***

So I have had a go with the help of the answer I got. The img click events aren't working, I'm guessing that somehow I have to attach the click handlers after I append them to the page. how? After that, I just need to do the settings!

[ratings control](http://jsfiddle.net/no1_melman/fz52E/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a plugin in jQuery use the following syntax

```
$.fn.setRed = function(){
  return $(this).each(function(){ //this is required for jQuery chaining to work and also if multiple html objects are passed
    var _obj = $(this);
    //work on the object here
    _obj.css("background-color", "red");
  });
}
```

You can then use

```
$(".ratings").setRed();
```

Comment: Changed the code, you can copy and paste the code in your project. It will set all backgrounds of the specified selector to red

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how I use all the other functions that I created in my fiddle along with what you have put? Like how to use the mouseover functions etc.

Comment: I saw your code. In your plugin you should not use absolute selectors like '#rating'. Convert them to relative selectors to the $(this) object. This is one reason why I have stored the $(this) as _obj, which is a closure